# Inserting from a database to another using where clause

Tags: mysql

```
DATABASE A           DATABASE B
TABLE ABC            TABLE ABC
NAME   ACNO          NAME   ACNO
A        4444        A      4444
B        4444        B      4444
C        5555        C      5555
                     D      5555
```

how to insert to a database A  table name ABC and specific account 5555 FROM database B table name ABC a specific account 5555

Comment: Your question is not clear, please clarify if this is what you are asking: "how to insert a specific record from database B (- table ABC), into database A (- table ABC)?"

Comment: yes,but i want only the acno=5555

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO A.ABC (NAME, ACNO) 
SELECT NAME, ACNO FROM B.ABC WHERE ACNO=5555
```

Obviously replacing "A" and "B" with your database names.